# My first web wp-blog-header.phd

Tags: wp-blog-header.php

This is my first time making af webside and I have by an accident deleted somthing in/ at my File manager. (I thougth it was the blog part that i do not need ) but Now the webside is white and it calls for this:

wp-blog-header.php

I can see that wp-blog-header.php have 0 KB now, how do i repear? and find the file again?

PLS help me I'm autodidak Can i rescue the page?

Comment: Perform a manual update, using these instructions: https://codex.wordpress.org/Upgrading_WordPress#Manual_Update, to make sure WordPress has all the right files.

Answer (score 0):

On the official Wp github repository you can find the file you are talking about, but maybe check your wp version before, so that you grab the version of the file corresponding to your wp install.

https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-blog-header.php